# Flask-Restplus, changing content-type in swagger

Tags: swagger, content-type, flask-restplus

I am using flask_restplus to generate swagger. I have to accept Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded on one of the POST endpoint. But the auto generated swagger document only shows applicatin/json. How can I change this behavior? Thanks.

Comment: As I'm working on something similar: How did you set the `Content-Type` you'd like to accept? Could you post some example code?

Answer (score 2):

Just stumbled on this myself, and found a workaround.

The fix is to use `@api.expect` to annotate the method, not the class.

For example, say you have a parser called `someparser` that has an attribute with `location='form'`.

Instead of

```
@api.route('/someroute')
@api.expect(someparser)
class SomeResource(Resource):
    def post(self):
        ...
```

You should do

```
@api.route('/someroute')
class SomeResource(Resource):
    @api.expect(someparser)
    def post(self):
        ...
```

Comment: This response was very helpful. 

Additionally I would like to pinpoint to: https://github.com/noirbizarre/flask-restplus/issues/92 for a parser example:
parser = api.parser()
parser.add_argument('resource_name', type=str, help='Resource name', location='form')